# Is there list syntax sugar "[:]" for dictionaries in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

We can do the following for lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = []
>>> id(a)
140093169968840
>>> id(b)
140093169868528
>>> b[:] = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> id(b)
140093169868528
```

`b` retains memory reference

Is there a way to do the same for two dictionaries in Python 2.7?

```
>>> a = {'one' :1, 'two' :2}
>>> b = {}
>>> b[...] = a  # ?
```

UPDATE: The answer is "No, there's no syntax sugar for dictionaries."
It's not a duplicate. I'm not looking for a way to do it, othere that using syntax sugar.

Comment: @Mel I do not see syntax sugar in those answers

Comment: That's because there isn't one, but just saying *"no"* doesn't tell you how to get anything done!

Comment: That's because there isn't any. `clear/update` is the equivalent.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanx

Comment: Slice syntax has a clear meaning in lists, *from index a to index b*. Within *unordered* dicts, that syntax makes no sense.